# How is the material $\ce{\alpha-NaMnO2}$ pronounced?

Tags: magnetism, terminology

I am a theoretical physicist, so I am not very familiar with chemical names. The material I am interested in is $\ce{\alpha-NaMnO2}$. Would that be pronounced *alpha sodium manganese dioxide*? Is it important to say the $\alpha$?

If it's relevant, I'm talking about [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **2020,** *124* (19), No. 197203](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.124.197203).

*Apologies if this is a trivial question, I tried looking up the answer, it may just be that I am not using the correct search terms.*

Comment: To be honest, this would fit much better on [Chemistry.se].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The anions of the form $\ce{MnO_x^y-}$ are referred to as manganates (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manganate)). I'm not sure if there might be a "special" name for $\ce{MnO2^-}$ specifically (that's the species you have here) because I never encountered this anion in my lab times, but given that $\ce{MnO4^2-}$ are the "normal" manganates and $\ce{MnO4^-}$ the permanganates, I think manganate would be the term used here as well.

Now to distinguish the ambiguity in $x$ and $y$ you usually add the oxidation state of the central metal (in this case manganese) in the form of roman numbers. Since actually the same stoichiometric formula ($\ce{NaMnO2}$) could give rise to different stable crystal structures (depending on external conditions) one uses the greek letter to distinguish between these different structures. So, yes, to be precise the $\alpha$ is needed and I would call the compound **$\alpha$-Sodium-manganate(III)** pronounced "alpha sodium manganate three".

But in day to day conversations one would rarely use the full thing if it is clear from context. First thing usually the $\alpha$ is dropped and next the (III). So taking to a lab colleague, where it is clear you can just say Sodium manganate.

**Update:** I just saw that the [materialsproject](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-18957/) has something on your compound under ID mp-18957, where they tagged it as `Sodium manganese(III) oxide`.

Comment: I think the best best way to talk about it depends on the context. The more familiar someone is with you/the project, the more informal.

Comment: @kskinnerx16 Agreed. In the right circumstances it might be referred to as simply "NMO".

Comment: It is not manganate. Sodium manganese(III) oxide; or sodium manganese dioxide is the correct name.

Comment: To back up the other comment with manganese in a comparatively low oxidation state it is probably best viewed as a mixed memtal oxide - I doubt there are discrete MnO2- ions in the lattice.